# Pass this element and get in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I get the current this element clicked with onclick event. This is my html code:

```
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger" onclick="launchTrigger(this);">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger" onclick="launchTrigger(this);">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger" onclick="launchTrigger(this);">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
```

This is my function:

```
function launchTrigger(this) {

        var $this = $(this);
        alert($this);
        $this.toggleClass('is-selected').find('i').toggleClass('is-selected');
        $this.parents('.pg-features').find('ul').toggleClass('list-open');
}
```

But this report me this error in Chrome console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: launchTrigger is not defined
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: the function is being triggered by the click? I didn't understand

Comment: you can't have a function parameter called `this` - look at your developer tools console, you'll see an error telling you as much - firefox will say `SyntaxError: missing formal parameter` for example pointing to that function definition ... chrome should be telling you `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this(…)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: *"...in pure javascript"* I assume by that you mean "using the DOM, not a library." Since you're obviously using jQuery, why do you want to do this without the help jQuery gives you?

Answer (score 3):

> You can not accept `"this"` as argument name because it is a `reserved keyword`.

Also add [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in `click-handler` to *cancel the event*.

```js
function launchTrigger(elem, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(elem);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger" onclick="launchTrigger(this,event);">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger" onclick="launchTrigger(this,event);">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger" onclick="launchTrigger(this,event);">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
```

Another [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/9v5nr8nr/2/) suggested by [**Jaromanda X**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x)

Comment: the onclick should be `launchTrigger(this);return false;` perhaps? or `return launchTrigger(this);` and `launchTrigger` can (optionally if you want) `return false`

Comment: Yes but in my code the alert return me null, why this? o_O

Comment: @JaromandaX, Your solutions will work too..Any harm if I do no `return false`, will `undefined` create any mess ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you have to return false, not just a falsey value like undefined

Comment: What if I omit `return` statement ?

Comment: Here's the story on `return false`: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html *(disclaimer: my blog)*

Answer (score 1):

> But this report me this error in Chrome console:
>
> > Uncaught ReferenceError: launchTrigger is not defined
>
> How to fix this problem?

Functions called from `onxyz="..."` attributes must be **global** functions. (One of several reasons not to use them.) It would appear from the error that your function is not declared globally, but probably within a scoping function of some kind.

Move it out to global scope and it will work provided you fix the name of your function argument, because `this` is a reserved word. But of course, that's at the cost of creating Yet Another Global. There are already far too many globals kicking around web pages and often conflicting with one another.

Instead, use modern event handling to hook up the handler using `addEventListener` (`attachEvent` on old IE).

Comment: "One of several reasons not to use them." - by "them", I guess you mean onclick attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot believe all the JQUERY answers while someone specifically asks for a pure javascript solution.

If you want to return the element you clicked on, you can use:

```js
function whoami(event) {
  var test = event.target.id;
  alert(test);
  console.log(test);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="whoami(event)">
```

Comment: Probably because OP used jQuery in the question, hence the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Instated of onclick event you can add jquery click event on class 
i have added the working code here please have a look on it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(document).on("click", ".launchTrigger", function(e) {
    alert($(this));
    $(this).toggleClass('is-selected').find('i').toggleClass('is-selected');
    $(this).parents('.pg-features').find('ul').toggleClass('list-open');
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger launchTrigger js-FeaturesTrigger">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger launchTrigger js-FeaturesTrigger">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger launchTrigger js-FeaturesTrigger">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the code out of the markup perhaps:

```
function launchTrigger() {
  var $this = $(this);
  alert($this);
  $this.toggleClass('is-selected').find('i').toggleClass('is-selected');
  $this.parents('.pg-features').find('ul').toggleClass('list-open');
}
```

add using JavaScript:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger');
Array.prototype.map.call(elems, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", launchTrigger, false);
});
```

Revised markup:

```
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="h6 label grey-link pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger">Learn more about Personal<i class="icon-down icon-small "></i></a>
```

Note for jQuery to use the function as you have it: use apply and take out the parameter

```
$('.pg-features-trigger.js-FeaturesTrigger').on('click', function(e) {
  launchTrigger.apply(this);
});
```

**EDIT:** NOTE If you do like parameter approach you can use the event target like so:

```
function launchTriggerEvent(event) {
  var $this = $(event.target);
  alert($this);
  alert(event.type);// alerts "click"
  $this.toggleClass('is-selected').find('i').toggleClass('is-selected');
  $this.parents('.pg-features').find('ul').toggleClass('list-open');
}
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('pg-features-trigger js-FeaturesTrigger');
Array.prototype.map.call(elems, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", launchTriggerEvent, false);
});
```